# Using VBA for a POST request to the Spotify Accounts service via REST API

Tags: vba, rest, spotify

I'm trying to retrieve data from my spotify-account and put it in an Excelsheet. I want to create some VBA-code to access the data using the Spotify Web Api.

I followed the [Spotify Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) but I'm stuck when I try to request the access token. I have to make a POST request to the Spotify Accounts service, but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using an "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" to do the post Request. Here is part of the code

```
Set HttpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HttpRequest.Open "POST", "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
HttpRequest.SetRequestHeader
HttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & strClient_secret
HttpRequest.Send ("grant_type=authorization_code&code=" & strCode & "&redirect_uri=http://www.js76.nl/diskkoffer/")
```

The response text says "Oops! Something went wrong, please try again or check out our help area.", but I can't figure out what went wrong. I don't have any experience with these http requests.

The strings strClient_secret and strCode are filled in another part of the program.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a spotify account so, not sure with the user name password. But their doc says that they have REST implementation, so your credentials need to be 64 bit encoded.

In this line `HttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & strClient_secret`

the variable `strClient_secret` needs to be 64 bit encoded.

so try adding a function like this, while replacing the place holders with correct user name and password.

```
Private Function EncodeBase64() As String
    arrData = StrConv(<<YOUR_SPOTIFY_USERID>> & ":" & <<YOUR_SPOTIFY_USERPASS>>, vbFromUnicode)

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

then change the line above to :
`HttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64`

have a look here for REST and VBA: http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/08/excel-vba-json-rest-with-jira-json-is.html

It will set you on correct route hopefully.

Comment: Do you need a reference to MSXML2?

Comment: yup, you do. Unless you want to use late binding.

Comment: Thx cyboashu for your answer. I think it set me on the right route, but I'm not there yet. I managed to encode the username/password. At first the output contained 2 lines, which gave me error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument". When I remove the 'line feed' the error is gone but I still get the Spotify error page as response text.

Comment: Later I read in the Spotify documentation "An alternative way of sending the client id and secret is as request parameters (client_id and client_secret) in the POST body, instead of sending them base64-encoded in the header.". I also tried that, sending the request without header and with the username/password in the body. But unfortunately with the same responsetext that says "Oops! Something went wrong"...